# global variable not working when the same variable works when declared in a function

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, global-variables

I'm trying to print a char* to the screen without the standard library by accessing video memory in C using this function:

```
int printchar(char c) {
        int videohex = 0xb8000;
        char* vidmem = (char*) videohex;
        *vidmem = c;
        videohex = videohex + 2;
}
```

The code prints the variable c to the screen as expected, but when I declare videohex as a global variable (I will use this variable throughout the program), using this code:

```
int videohex = 0xb8000;

int printchar(char c) {
        char* vidmem = (char*) videohex;
        *vidmem = c;
        videohex = videohex + 2;
}
```

Nothing is printed out.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can we see the function call. In the first function you are changing `videohex` the local variable by 2 which has no effect. In the second function you are modifying a global variable.

Comment: incrementing 2 to videohex makes the function print to a different position on-screen.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why don't you just declare `char *vidmem = (char*) 0xb8000;` as a global variable?

Comment: Why do you increment `videohex` before exiting the function? In the first function, this has no effect since it's a local variable that won't be used again.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you're incrementing `videohex` at the end of the function.

When it's a local variable, each time you call the function it's reinitialized to `0xb8000`.

When it's a global variable, it retains the updated value between calls. The next time you call the function, it will write to a different memory location. Eventually you'll increment it past the end of the video memory.

What you should probably use is two variables. One points to the base of the video memory, another is an offset for the current character. You can increment the offset, and when you reach the end it can wrap back around to `0`.

There's no need for both `int` and `char *` variables, you can simply initialize the pointer as you want:

```
const char *video_base = (char *)0xb8000;
unsigned int video_offset = 0;
#define VIDEO_MAX 0x1000

int printchar (char c) {
    video_base[video_offset] = c;
    video_offset += 2;
    if (video_offset >= VIDEO_MAX) {
        video_offset = 0;
    }
}
```